# Flutter State changing but page doesn't changes

Tags: flutter, dart, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a website using the package web_scraper, where I want the user to click a button and the new link opens where new scrapped images can be shown.

```
class Top2 extends StatefulWidget {
const Top2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<Top2> createState() => _Top2State();
}

class _Top2State extends State<Top2> {
 late List<Map<String, dynamic>> top2Wall;
 bool top2Loaded = false;
 int page = 2;

void top2Fetch() async {
final top2Scraper = WebScraper('https://mobile.alphacoders.com');

if (await top2Scraper
    .loadWebPage('/by-category/3?page=$page&quickload=1')) {
  top2Wall = top2Scraper.getElement('div.item > a > img', ['src', 'title']);

  // ignore: avoid_print
  print(top2Wall);
  setState(() {
    top2Loaded = true;
  });
}
  }

 @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
   top2Fetch();
}

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return Scaffold(
    body: top2Loaded

        // ignore: sized_box_for_whitespace
        ? Container(
            height: screenSize.height,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              child: Wrap(children: [
                for (int i = 1; i < top2Wall.length; i++)
                  WallCard(src: top2Wall[i]['attributes']['src']),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      page++;
                      
                      // ignore: avoid_print
                      print(page);
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan)),
                )
              ]),
            ),
          )
        : const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.cyanAccent),
          ));
    }[image2][1]
    }
```

For a clear explanation I want to change the page link for scraping, so basically the page number=1 i want to increase it by a number, when user clicks on the container. I used SetState and page++ to increment it by a digit everytime the user clicks on it. I used the print statement to check wether the page increments or not and its sucessfully increases but the page remains same, for clear code view please refer these images [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cLT9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07PUw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what your issue is, after calling increment page ++ in setstate, you have to call top2Fetch() again inside the onTap method. Like this:

```
onTap: ()async {
setState(()=>page++);
await top2Fetch();
}
```

Then update your UI.

You can include a bool value called isLoading in the onTap method: such that when you call the top2Fetch method , a loading spinner is shown on the UI till the future is done.

Comment: Thankyou so much it worked, but could you please tell why we using a asynchronus function with onTap I get it we need it to use together with await function  but I clearly don't understand

Comment: @CheemsMonarch Because the top2Fetch() is implicitly a future of type void